# Quintic QN8007B RoHS information?

Tags: integrated-circuit, manufacturing, production, buying, rohs

We are planning to use the Quintic QN8007B FM transmitter in our new design because it is quite cheap and has I2S interface. I believe this chip is no longer produced, but it is possible to get hold of old stock items (guaranteed not to be fake). Although we usually don't use obsolete products, this product will only be produced once in a small volume < 10k units.

For our CE marking, we need to have documentation that all chips are RoHS compliant, including the FM transmitter. Unfortunately it seems that Quintic does not exist anymore. NXP acquired Quintic's Bluetooth Low Energy (BTLE) and Wearable businesses in 2015, but I don't know if the FM transmitter product lineup was included in that. I've contacted NXP, and they say that they don't have any information about the QN8007B.

So my question is where to get RoHS information for the QN8007B? Or information about who bought the FM transmitter product lineup from Quintic?

Note: I know that some products like car FM-transmitters sold in Europe today use FM transmitters from Quintic, so this information must be available somewhere (at least if the manufacturer follows the CE regulations). I also know that many chip-brokers sell the QN8007B with date code 2018 and 2019, which should indicate that the chip was produced also after NXP bought part of Quintic. But this could of course also be fake chips.

Edit: Please find the datasheet [here](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1028101/Quintic/QN8007LB/1)

Comment: Please link to a device data sheet. If there is no DS available then it would appear to be foolish to be designing it into something.

Comment: @Andyaka Added data sheet to question

Comment: It is Pb-free if that's any help. Nice chip but largely superseded by blueTooth.

Comment: Yes, and it's probably RoHS compliant as well since it was produced at least until 2015. But I need the documentation to be able to use it.. The alternative is si4721 which is super expensive in comparison

Comment: Trouble is this: this site isn't a shopping site and, by shopping I mean "where can I find this or that or does somebody have this or that they can email me". It's a question and answer site and asking for stuff on the internet that you can't find is off-topic.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks, that was really helpful

Comment: This site does have drawbacks in this respect but these are the site rules and I for one try to respect them. No need to be sarcastic BTW.

Comment: The problem as I see it is that, although the device almost certainly *was* RoHS coimpliant, you can't provide the documentation to prove it ! Rant at 'civil servants' for drafting pointless and stupid regulations ... In view of this, the suppliers of these chips won't be able to sell them at all ! Except to China/wherever. Can the supplier not help ? Surely it's in their interest.